# Eloquent relationship give [ticket_id] does not exist on this collection instance laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am have some issue with eloquent relationship my first time working with it, after selecting and displaying list of selected events, I want to also select the **ticket_id** base on the **event_id** common between both(events and events_ticket) table, thanks for the help

**Error Showing** ->
Trying to get property 'ticket_id' of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\mahive\resources\views\tickets\index.blade.php)

**Both Model**

```
class EventsTicket extends Model
{
    public $table = "events_ticket";
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'event_id',
        'ticket_id',
        'ticket_name',
        'ticket_amount',
        'ticket_sold',
    ];

    public function event() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Event');
    }
}

class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'event_id',
        'event_name',
        'event_category',
        'event_type',
        'event_mode',
        'event_description',
        'event_image'
    ];

    public function userModel() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function eticket() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventsTicket');
    }
}
```

***Controller***

```
public function index()
{
    $events = Event::where('ticket_statue', 'active')->with('eticket')->get();
    return view('tickets.index', ['event_data' => $events]); 
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($event_data as $event)
    {{ ucwords($event->event_name) }}
    {{ $event->eticket->ticket_id  }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code every Event has many eticket. Try this:

```
@foreach($event_data as $event)
    {{ ucwords($event->event_name) }}
    {{ optional($event->eticket->first())->ticket_id  }}
@endforeach
```

Use `optional` because there may not be any etickets.

Comment: Hi, I have added this `{{ optional($event->eticket->first())->ticket_id  }}` but nothing is showing only this `{{ ucwords($event->event_name) }}` is showing.

Comment: Hi, because the $event does not have any tickets. Are you sure `$event` has any `etickets`?

Comment: Sorry when you mean does `$event` has any `etickets` do you mean as a field in the database cause I added the **etickets to the model** see this `class Event extends Model
{
    public function eticket() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventsTicket');
    }
}`

Comment: I have add my DB image to the question.

Comment: I mean, Is there any data in the `events_tickets` table to be related to `event` table?

Comment: Yes, there is data in `events_ticket` that is related to `event` they both has a field that is both related to each other with is `event_id`

Comment: Show me all columns of the events  table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240450/discussion-between-dotun-seyi-and-mohammadmahdi-baleghsefat).